# Using additional command line arguments with gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

Assuming I'm starting a Flask app under gunicorn as per http://gunicorn.org/deploy.html#runit, is there a way for me to include/parse/access additional command line arguments?

E.g., can I include and parse the `foo` option in my Flask application somehow?

```
gunicorn mypackage:app --foo=bar
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can't pass command line arguments directly but you can choose application configurations easily enough.

```
$ gunicorn 'mypackage:build_app(foo="bar")'
```

Will call the function "build_app" passing the foo="bar" kwarg as expected. This function should then return the WSGI callable that'll be used.

Comment: Thanks! Got here when searching for how to pass multiple arguments. Turned out to be as simple as passing them as comma separated values; for e.g. `(foo="bar", foo1="bar1")`

Comment: Note that this doesn't work in `gunicorn>=20`, you'll get a `Failed to find application object 'build_app(foo="there")' in 'mypackage'` error. See https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2159

Comment: You can pass a custom name for the app (`-n xyz-app`) and use as an identifier (`import sys, re; appid = re.search(r'\-n\s{1,}([^\s|$]+)', ''.join(sys.argv)).group(1)`)..

Answer (score 13):

I usually put it in `__init.py__` after `main()` and then I can run with or without gunicorn (assuming your `main()` supports other functions too).

```
# __init__.py

# Normal entry point
def main():
  ...

# Gunicorn entry point generator
def app(*args, **kwargs):
    # Gunicorn CLI args are useless.
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495367/
    #
    # Start the application in modified environment.
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668947/
    #
    import sys
    sys.argv = ['--gunicorn']
    for k in kwargs:
        sys.argv.append("--" + k)
        sys.argv.append(kwargs[k])
    return main()
```

That way you can run simply with e.g.

```
gunicorn 'app(foo=bar)' ...
```

and your `main()` can use standard code that expects the arguments in `sys.argv`.