# Setting command line arguments for main function tests

Tags: python, pytest, argparse

I have a main() function in python that gets command line arguments.
Is there a way for me to write pytest tests for this function and define the arguments in the code?

e.g.

```
def main():
    # argparse code
    args, other = arg_parser.parse_known_args()
    return args.first_arg


def test_main():
    res = main() # call with first_arg = "abc"
    assert(res == "abc")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`parse_args` takes a `argv` parameter.  The docs uses this repeatedly in it's examples

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('bar')
parser.parse_known_args(['--foo', '--badger', 'BAR', 'spam'])
```

where the string list replicates `sys.argv[1:]` that it would get from the commandline.  If the argument is `None` (or omitted) the parser uses `sys.argv[1:]`.

So if

```
def main(argv=None):
    # argparse code
    args, other = arg_parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    return args.first_arg
```

You could test with

```
main(['foo', '-f','v'])
```

The `unittesting` file for `argparse.py` uses both this approach, and your's of modifying `sys.argv` directly.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#beyond-sys-argv

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#partial-parsing

Comment: How does your solution play with a pytest test?

Answer (score 18):

To add to the previous answers, instead of modifying `sys.argv` It is safer to use a context manager which can cover up and protect the underlying object. An example would be

```
with unittest.mock.patch('sys.argv', ['program_name', '--option1', 'inputFile']):
    main()
```

This works only with python3. For python2 the [Mock](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/index.html) library does the trick.

I found this solution on a different stackoverflow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18668947/how-do-i-set-sys-argv-so-i-can-unit-test-it#comment55008523_27765993).

Comment: The context manager is a great addition. You do need to add one extra first string to the list, because the first string in `sys.argv` gets ignored by argparse. So something like `['junk', '--option1', 'inputFile']`.

Answer (score 5):

The best solution I found so far is this

```
def test_main():
    sys.argv = ["some_name", "abc"]
    res = main()
```

and for flags:

```
sys.argv.append("-f")
sys.argv.append("v")
```

Answer (score 0):

For an entrypoint.py this might be particularly simple to add an extra argument. In this case `--disable-warnings`

```py
import sys

import pytest


if __name__ == "__main__":
    exit_code = pytest.main(sys.argv[1:] + ["--disable-warnings"])
```