# Python 2.6 Unittest assistance with parameters and argparse, how to solve?

Tags: python, unit-testing, argparse, python-unittest, parameterized-unit-test

I am trying to run a basic unit test on Python 2.6 that takes arguments with argparse.

I am limited in my environment and cannot install any further libraries or use any modules for testing but unittest.

However I believe the answer lies here:

[How do you write tests for the argparse portion of a python module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18160078/how-do-you-write-tests-for-the-argparse-portion-of-a-python-module)

However I am having trouble refactoring the provided main answer with my code.

Without refactoring my example code I have provided, can someone please show me the light and show me how to write a unittest for the below code, that takes the -H and -S on the fly?

Thanks in advance.

```py
#!python
import argparse
import sys

try:
    HOSTNAME = sys.argv[2]
    SOMESTRING = sys.argv[3]
except IndexError:
    print "Please Enter the Hostname and Somestring"


def argparse_msg():
    return "testscript_example -H somehost -S somestring"


def check_arg(args=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A Test Example", usage=argparse_msg())
    parser.add_argument("-H", "--host",
                        help="HostName",
                        required=True)

    parser.add_argument("-S", "--somestring",
                        help="HostName",
                        required=True)

    results = parser.parse_args(args)

    return (results.host, results.somestring)


def message_test():
    print HOSTNAME + " " + SOMESTRING


def main():
    message_test()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOSTNAME, SOMESTRING = check_arg(sys.argv[1:])
    main()
```

Comment: When using `unittest` (or other testing package), you can't supply commandline values for your own script.  The commandline is for `unittest` itself (which has its own parser).  Other links: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51710083/how-to-run-pytest-with-a-specified-test-directory-on-a-file-that-uses-argparse, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42331049/how-to-test-python-classes-that-depend-on-argparse

Comment: Still trying to get my head around it, would be great if you could show a basic example in code....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To facilitate test class, I have modified the code as following:

- Removed global variables (e.g.: `HOSTNAME`, `SOMESTRING`)
- Passed parameters to functions
- Returned string from function rather than printing (from `message_test` and `main`)

Updated code `receiver.py`:

```
#!python
import argparse
import sys


def argparse_msg():
    return "testscript_example -H somehost -S somestring"


def check_arg(args=None):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="A Test Example", usage=argparse_msg())
    parser.add_argument("-H", "--host",
                        help="HostName",
                        required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-S", "--somestring",
                        help="HostName",
                        required=True)
    results = parser.parse_args(args)
    return (results.host, results.somestring)


def message_test(HOSTNAME, SOMESTRING):
    return "{} {}".format(HOSTNAME, SOMESTRING)


def main(HOSTNAME, SOMESTRING):
    return message_test(HOSTNAME, SOMESTRING)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOSTNAME, SOMESTRING = check_arg(sys.argv[1:])
    print(main(HOSTNAME, SOMESTRING))
```

Output of running `receiver.py`:

```
python receiver.py -H localhost -S demo
localhost demo
```

Test file (`test_receiver.py`):

```
from receiver import check_arg
import unittest

class ParserTest(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_main(self):
        HOSTNAME, SOMESTRING = check_arg(['-H', 'test', '-S', 'sample string'])
        self.assertEqual(HOSTNAME, 'test')
        self.assertEqual(SOMESTRING, 'sample string')        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Output of running the `test_receiver.py`:

```
python test_receiver.py
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.001s

OK
```