# `__main__.py` structure with argparse, pytest and sphinxdoc

Tags: python, pytest, python-sphinx, runpy

For a small module, I want to have a `__main__.py` file that is executed via Pythons `-m` argument. As per basic docs, this file looks like

```
import argparse

from . import MyClass

def getparser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    # […]
    return parser


if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = getparser()
    args = parser.parse_args()
    c = MyClass()
    # […]
```

I want to test this with **runpy**:

```
import runpy

def test_main():
    runpy.run_module("mymodule")
    # […]
```

which does not work because the `__name__` in this case is not `__main__`. In principle one could omit the `if __name__ == "__main__"` condition to get this working.

But, I also want to document the routine with [**sphinxarg.ext**](https://sphinx-argparse.readthedocs.io). This requires to have the `getparser()` function available from sphinx. Removing the `if __name__ == "__main__"` condition then also runs the module within sphinxdoc, which is not what is wanted.

```
.. argparse::
   :module: mymodule.__main__
   :func: getparser
   :prog: myprog
```

How can I structure this so that all use cases work well ***and*** the code is well-readable (i.e. the ``getparser()` function and the main code should not be distributed over different files)?

Answer (score 0):

One method is to keep your `__main__.py` very thin and import what you need and run it.

So, you might extract your logic into another module, say `cli.py`, and write a `main` function that functions the same as your code block you have under `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

```py
# cli.py
def get_parser():
   """docstring"""
   ...


def main() -> int:
    parser = get_parser()
    ...
    return exit_code
```

Then in `__main__.py` you can simply have something like this, which will work with `runpy` (although this is maybe unnecessary now!) and doesn't need sphinx or test modules to import it:

```py
from .cli import main
raise SystemExit(main()) # optionally use `if __name__ == ...`
```

This way, you're still able to import everything from `cli.py` (or wherever you choose), test it, auto-document it, or whatever. With this approach you can also test your `main` function and not have the limitations that arise with trying to test using `runpy`.

```py
from mypackage.cli import main
def test_main():
    assert main() == 0
```

---

Extracting to a module like `cli.py` is technically optional. You could also keep all of this in `__main__.py`, but the main lesson is to minimize the amount of code under `if __name__ == '__main__':`. If I have this, it almost always looks something like this:

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() # or raise SystemExit(main())
```

You can also simply set `__name__` with the `run_name` keyword argument for `runpy.run_module`:

```py
def test_main():
    runny.run_module('mymodule', run_name='__main__')
```

But I would suggest that extracting a testable `main` function is a better testing approach.

Comment: The problem here is that calling `main()` ignores `sys.argv`.

Comment: @olebole if you mean for testing, you can patch sys.argv in your test to add arguments https://stackoverflow.com/a/70871265/5747944